# laravel 5.4 Undefined property: stdClass::$id

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have two models artists and songs which have one-many relations, an Artist can have multiple songs. song belongs to one artist.

```
$artists = DB::table('artists')->join('songs', 'artists.id', '=', 'songs.artist_id')->select('artists.*, songs.id, songs.title, songs.artist_id, songs.week_hits, songs.created_at')
            ->SELECT(DB::raw('sum(songs.week_hits) as WEEKHITS'))->groupBy('songs.artist_id')->orderBy('WEEKHITS', 'DESC')->take(7)->get();
 return return view('front.home', compact('videos', 'songs', 'artists', 'played', 'uploads', 'albums'));
```

this is my Controller code. as u can see I added all artists songs week_hits and grouped by songs.artist_id

and this is my view.

```
 @foreach($artists as $artist)
            <div class="artist-grid">
                <div class="art-img">
                    <a href="{{route('artist',['id' => $artist->id, 'slug' => $artist->slug])}}">
                        <img  src="image/small/{{$artist->image}}">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="name">
                    <h3>{{$artist->name}}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
             @endforeach
```

but when i dd($artists) i can see all collection returned but when i send to the view iam getting this error message.

```
(2/2) ErrorException
Undefined property: stdClass::$id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\front\home.blade.php)
```

but when I dd($artists) this is the output.

```
Collection {#293 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#307 ▼
      +"WEEKHITS": "39"
    }
    1 => {#292 ▼
      +"WEEKHITS": "9"
    }
    2 => {#278 ▼
      +"WEEKHITS": "4"
    }
    3 => {#308 ▼
      +"WEEKHITS": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

please really appreciate your help.

Comment: could you dd() the $artist collection value and show us the result of single entry?

Comment: this is when i dd($artists) variable.  Collection {#293 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#307 ▼
      +"WEEKHITS": "39"
    }
    1 => {#292 ▼
      +"WEEKHITS": "9"
    }
    2 => {#278 ▼
      +"WEEKHITS": "4"
    }
    3 => {#308 ▼
      +"WEEKHITS": "1"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Try return view as follow:

```
return view('front.home')->with($artists, compact('artists'));
```

**EDIT**
To pass multiple variables there are many solutions. Like:

```
return view('front.home')->with(compact('videos', 'songs', 'artists', 'played', 'uploads', 'albums'));
```

Comment: sorry i did not mention above, I am not only sending $artists variable to view, there is another views,  return view('front.home', compact('videos', 'songs', 'artists', 'played', 'uploads', 'albums'));

Comment: You can send multiple variables using multiple `with`. See my updated naswer @MahamoudMahamed

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on your query, you have to select also id in SELECT() option in query.

```
$artists = DB::table('artists')->join('songs', 'artists.id', '=', 'songs.artist_id')->select('artists.*, songs.id, songs.title, songs.artist_id, songs.week_hits, songs.created_at')
            ->SELECT(DB::raw('sum(songs.week_hits) as WEEKHITS','artists.id as id'))->groupBy('songs.artist_id')->orderBy('WEEKHITS', 'DESC')->take(7)->get();
```

OR

```
  $artists = DB::table('artists')->join('songs', 'artists.id', '=', 'songs.artist_id')->select('artists.*, songs.id, songs.title, songs.artist_id, songs.week_hits, songs.created_at')
                ->SELECT(DB::raw('sum(songs.week_hits) as WEEKHITS','artists.*'))->groupBy('songs.artist_id')->orderBy('WEEKHITS', 'DESC')->take(7)->get();
```

Comment: still no change i did but of them. i think the problem is this part.  <a href="{{route('artist',['id' => $artist->id, 'slug' => $artist->slug])}}">          . as you can se it can not find the property of id route $artist->id

Comment: please dd() within foreach() then u can see the actual situation of $artist object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your query, you are selecting twice, the second select statement is overriding the first one, that's why you are only getting "WEEKHITS"
combine both of the select statements.